# How do I use Brother software to scan to Email?

Tags: windows-7, printer, network-printer, scanner

I have a Brother MFC 6490CW and we recently installed the software for it on Windows 7.

Before it automatically opened Outlook 2010 when we told it to scan to an email because it was the default mail program.

Now Outlook isn't listed in the options when configuring the software for the printer (Control center 3 from Brother). When I browse to where the outlook executable file is, it scans and when it goes to open outlook it starts and then says;

> Cannot start Microsoft Outlook. The command line argument is not
>   valid. Verify the switch you are using.

I'm not even sure what the command for it is since it's happening behind the scenes. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is Outlook installed, setup and working? I did not find that model number on the list of [Windows 7 Compatible Models](http://www.brother-usa.com/lp/windows7compatibility.aspx#.US5wmDetl_g) on the Brother site.

Comment: Yes it is. Everything with outlook works perfectly.

Comment: It is Windows 7 compatible, here's the printer: http://www.brother-usa.com/downloads/default.aspx?PGID=5&R3ModelID=MFC6490CW#.US58WzDvtyw

Comment: Here's the download for the software for Win7, Win8 etc: http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/dlf/download_top.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc6490cw_all

Comment: And if you look here you'll see the Win7 driver for that model: http://www.brother-usa.com/lp/windows7compatibility.aspx#.US58sDDvtyw

Comment: Oops, I had 4690 in my question, that should have been 6490, my bad. Just edited it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found on the Brother site in the **FAQs & Troubleshooting** for the MFC-6490CW.

> I cannot use the Scan to E-mail with Outlook2003 or Outlook2007 after
>   updating ControlCenter3. The error message "command line argument is
>   invalid" appears. What can I do?

Brother's answer is to [re-update Control Center 3](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/BSC/public/us/us/en/faq/faq/000000/002400/000083/faq002483_003.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc6490cw_all&Cat=117).

It is listed for Outlook 2003 & 2007. It's worth a try, but I am not sure if it will work with Outlook 2010 or not.